# How many bytes should I read/write to a socket?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm having some doubts about the number of bytes I should write/read through a socket in C on Unix. I'm used to sending 1024 bytes, but this is really too much sometimes when I send short strings.

I read a string from a file, and I don't know how many bytes this string is, it can vary every time, it can be 10, 20 or 1000. I only know for sure that it's < 1024. So, when I write the code, I don't know the size of bytes to read on the client side, (on the server I can use `strlen()`). So, is the only solution to always read a maximum number of bytes (1024 in this case), regardless of the length of the string I read from the file?

For instance, with this code:

```
read(socket,stringBuff,SIZE);
```

wouldn't it be better if `SIZE` is 10 instead of 1024 if I want to read a 10 byte string?

Comment: `recv()` returns the number of byte received through socket.

Comment: Please don't use one question to advertise a different one.

Comment: @timrau Yes, I know, read too, but if I'm not wrong, when you write a read call, you should write something like read(socket,stringBuff,SIZE), and in the SIZE you've to specify the number of char you want to read. Whant I mean, if I read a 10 char string, wouldn't it be better if SIZE is 10 instead of 1024?

Comment: Read enough bytes for the header of whatever protocol you are using, and then work out the expected length from that header, and then read that many bytes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code in your question, if there are only 10 bytes to be read, then it makes no difference whether `SIZE` is 10 bytes, 1,024 bytes, or 1,000,024 bytes - it'll still just read 10 bytes. The only difference is how much memory you set aside for it, and if it's possible for you to receive a string up to 1,024 bytes, then you're going to have to set aside that much memory anyway.

However, regardless of how many bytes you are trying to read in, you always have to be prepared for the possibility that `read()` will actually read a different number of them. Particularly on a network, when you can get delays in transmission, even if your server is sending a 1,024 byte string, less than that number of bytes may have arrived by the time your client calls `read()`, in which case you'll read less than 1,024.

So, you always have to be prepared for the need to get your input in more than one `read()` call. This means you need to be able to tell when you're done reading input - you can't rely alone on the fact that `read()` has returned to tell you that you're done. If your server might send more than one message before you've read the first one, then you obviously can't hope to rely on this.

You have three main options:

1. Always send messages which are the same size, perhaps padding smaller strings with zeros if necessary. This is usually suboptimal for a TCP stream. Just read until you've received exactly this number of bytes.
2. Have some kind of sentinel mechanism for telling you when a message is over. This might be a newline character, a `CRLF`, a blank line, or a single dot on a line followed by a blank line, or whatever works for your protocol. Keep reading until you have received this sentinel. To avoid making inefficient system calls of one character at a time, you need to implement some kind of buffering mechanism to make this work well. If you can be sure that your server is sending you lines terminated with a single `'\n'` character, then using `fdopen()` and the standard C I/O library may be an option.
3. Have your server tell you how big the message is (either in an initial fixed length field, or using the same kind of sentinel mechanism from point 2), and then keep reading until you've got that number of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

The `read()` system call blocks until it can read one or more bytes, or until an error occurs.

It DOESN'T guarantee that it will read the number of bytes you request! With TCP sockets, it's very common that `read()` returns less than you request, because it can't return bytes that are still propagating through the network.

So, you'll have to check the return value of `read()` and call it again to get more data if you didn't get everything you wanted, and again, and again, until you have everything.